# Adding foreign key fails unless data is first removed and reinserted after

Tags: sql, constraints, sql-server-2016

I have an odd issue with foreign keys. I am trying to perform the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE [GroupMember] FOREIGN KEY ([Group]) REFERENCES [Group]([GUID])
```

Which gives me the following error:

> > The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__GroupMember__Group__0D25C822". The conflict occurred in database "x", table "dbo.Group", column 'GUID'.

I then verified the existing things, which I have confirmed are all ok:

- Referenced table (dbo.Group) has a defined PRIMARY KEY on [GUID] column
- Referencing table (dbo.GroupMember) has no [Group]-values which do not exist in [GUID]-column of dbo.Group-table
- No similarly referencing foreign keys exist already

From here on, I experimented. Taking some rows in and out, wiping the table, truncating the table. What I can conclude so far:

- If I wipe the referencing table using `DELETE FROM [GroupMember];` then try to apply the FK constraint, I receive the same error message
- If I truncate the referencing table using `TRUNCATE TABLE [GroupMember];`, I can apply the FK constraint without  errors. Additionally, I am able to reinsert the exact same data after applying the FK constraint, without problems.

From this I can conclude that the data itself is not the problem. Can anyone make sense of this? Why am I able to apply the constraint after truncating the table, but not after deleting all records?

Comment: Did you try using the `WITH NOCHECK` option with the `alter table` statement?

Comment: Hey Todd. If I add the constraint with the NOCHECK hint, it works.

Comment: Does your column allow NULL values?

Comment: Hi Woozar. The referencing column is nullable, the referenced column is a non-nullable column with clustered PK. I have tried removing all referencing columns with NULL, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft SSMS check whether unchecking "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation" solves the problem. You'll find this in Options > Designers > Table and Database Designers.

I have had similar issues that have been resolved by this. Let me know if it works or not.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your response. I have also encountered issues with this option in the past, so it has been disabled for a while, I double checked it now.